# Export a function within its namespace?

Tags: c++, function, dll, namespaces, export

I'm fairly certain this isn't possible from what I've read, and tried. Although for ease and continuity in code I would like to ask here.

Is it possible to export a function along with its namespace container?

For example:

```
namespace Continuity
{
    int Foo(void);
}
```

Standard usage would be: `Continuity::Foo();`

I want to be able to export this function to use in a DLL, however I want to keep it in the namespace structure so that I can use the same usage in the DLL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You asked:

> Is it possible to export a function along with it's namespace container example:

Yes, it is possible.

Use:

```
namespace Continuity
{
   DLL_EXPORT int Foo(void);
}
```

Where `DLL_EXPORT` is `#define`d to either `__declspec(dllexport)` or `__declspec(dllimport)` appropriately.

In the project where you build the DLL, you'll need:

```
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
```

In projects where you use the DLL, you'll need:

```
#define DLL_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
```

Comment: This is pretty old, so I hope, you will answer. Does the namespace affect in any way the call of the dll? If not, I can get rid of it, if there are no side-effects within my project.

Comment: What do you mean by the call of the dll?

Comment: If I call a function of a dll like `_AddFunc = (AddFunc)GetProcAddress(hInstLibrary, "Add");`, does the namespace appear anywhere here or did it just "die"?

Comment: @MaestroGlanz, I don't any experience with that. However, searching through SO leads to a lot of questions and answers. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%2B%2B%5D+is%3Aq+GetProcAddress+namespace+function.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure not to use extern "C" when declaring the function otherwise the namespace is not used for linking the function. You may then have 2 dlls with the same function in 2 different namespaces but only one function will be called randomly based on the order the functions are loaded.